# Estimation on elliptic operator

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations

Assume the strongly elliptic property, i.e. 
$$\sum_{|\alpha|= m}a_\alpha \xi^\alpha\neq0,\ \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d\backslash\{0\},$$
and
$$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_\alpha i^{|\alpha|}\xi^\alpha\neq0,\ \forall \xi \in \mathbb{R}^d,$$
where $a_\alpha$ are complext constants and $\alpha$ are multiindices.

Is the following estimation valid?
$$|\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_\alpha i^{|\alpha|}\xi^\alpha|\geq \mathcal{K}(1+|\xi|^2)^{m/2},\ \forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^d.$$

If so, how to prove?

I am thinking about 
$$f(\tilde{\xi}) = f(t,\xi):=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_\alpha i^{|\alpha|}t^{m-|\alpha|}\xi^\alpha,$$
which is positive-homogeneous of order $m$ and $t^2+|\xi|^2 = |\tilde{\xi}|^2$.

Now the question would be how to argue that the value of $f(t,\xi)$ on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ is strictly possitive? Will it do the job?

Comment: In the linear case $m=1$, the estimation is true. Indeed, the "strong elliptic property" that you mention reduces to
$$\sum_{j=1}^d a_j\xi^j=0 \quad \iff \quad (\xi^1\ldots\xi^d)=0, $$
which holds if and only if $d=2$ and $a_1, a_2\in \mathbb{C}$ are $\mathbb{R}$-linearly independent. If that is the case then the map 
$$F\colon (\xi^1, \xi^2)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mapsto a_1\xi^1+a_2\xi^2\in \mathbb{C}$$ 
is a linear isomorphism [...]

Comment: [...]and so 
$$\lvert F(\xi)\rvert\ge \lvert\xi\rvert\left\lvert F\left(\frac{\xi}{\lvert \xi\rvert}\right)\right\rvert\ge \left(\min_{\mathbb{S}^1}\lvert F(\xi)\rvert\right)\lvert\xi\rvert,$$ when $\xi\ne 0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, sorry to ask you, but what have you proved? I can't see how your inequality implies the estimate proposed by OP.

Comment: @Tomás: No need to be sorry, you are right, there is some issue here. What I have tried to prove is that $$\lvert a_1\xi^1+a_2\xi^2\rvert \ge C \lvert \xi \rvert$$
which is *almost* the desired inequality with $m=1$, except that the $+1$ is missing from the right hand side.

Comment: The point is that the OP is considering non-homogeneous operators, because otherwise the desired conclusion 
$$ |\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}a_\alpha i^{|\alpha|}\xi^\alpha|\geq \mathcal{K}(1+|\xi|^2)^{m/2},\ \forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$$ 
would be trivially false (just let $\xi \to 0$).

Comment: The function $f(t,\xi)$ can have an imaginary part. Proving $|f(t,\xi)|>0$ on the unit sphere is enough.

Comment: @Andrew would you mind to elaborate a bit? I cannot really follow your comment.

Comment: @newbie For example, in one-dimensional case for polynomial $-\xi^2+\xi+1$ the function $f$ is $\xi^2+it \xi+t^2$ which is not positive.

Comment: @Andrew Yes you are right. But I need to prove the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments it is enough to prove that $f>0$ in the unit sphere of $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$: By continuity of $f$ and compctness of said sphere, $f>\mathcal{K}>0$ there so that, if $r^2=t^2+|\xi|^2$ then

$$
f(t,\xi)=r^mf \left( \frac{t}{r}, \frac{ \xi}{r} \right) > \mathcal{K}r^m,
$$
and taking $t=1$ gives the desired inequality.

To prove that $f>0$ on the unit sphere notice that, by your first condition of ellipticity,

$$
f(0,\xi)=\left| \sum_{|\alpha|=m} a_\alpha i^m \xi^{\alpha} \right| = \left| \sum_{|\alpha|=m} a_\alpha \xi^{\alpha} \right|>0.
$$

when $\xi\neq0$. If $t\neq 0$ then

$$
f(t, \xi)= |t|^mf \left( 1, \frac{\xi}{t} \right) >0 
$$
by your second condition, since $f(1, \xi)>0$ for all $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

This implies that $f(t, \xi)>0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1} \setminus  \{0\}$. Since the sphere is contained in this set we're done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind to elaborate the first step(why it is strictly positive)? I don't really get it.

Comment: @newbie: What parts are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: Why $\mathcal{K}>0$ exists?

Comment: It is a compactness argument: $f$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ so it's continuous. Assume that such a $\mathcal{K}$ doesn't exist, then there is a sequence $(t_n,\xi_n)$ in the sphere such that $f(t_n,\xi_n)\to 0$. By Bolzono-Wierstrass, this sequence has a convergent subsequence $(t_{n_k},\xi_{n_k}) \to (t,\xi)$. Since the sphere is closed $(t,\xi)$ is in the sphere so that, by continuity of $f$ we must have $f(t,\xi)=0$ which is a contradiction since we know $f$ is positive there.

Comment: It's clear now. Thanks a lot.